The median of $R$ (A subset of $S$) is an $\epsilon$-approximate median of $S$
Let $S$ be a set of $n$ distinct values. We say value $x$ is an $\epsilon$-approximate median if
$$\frac{n}{2} - n\epsilon \le rank(x) \le \frac{n}{2} +n\epsilon$$
We say $x$ is an $\epsilon$-approximate mean if
$$\mu (1-\epsilon) \le x \le \mu (1+\epsilon)$$
where $\mu$ is the mean values in $S$.
Consider sampling each element of $S$ with probability $p$ and let $R$ be resulting subset of $S$.
My task: Prove a lower bound on $p$ such that the median of $R$ is an $\epsilon$-approximate median of $S$ with probability at least $\frac{99}{100}$.
Could you please give me some hints for that problem?
p.s: The definition of rank $x \in S$ is the number of elements in $S$ that are $\le x$.
Many thanks
